# How to change selected radio button color

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have been started devloping a simple form recently where im trying to test diffrent properties of diffrent toolbox actions

im using radio button from MaterialSkin (Nuget Pakage) i dont know how could i change the selected color of the radio button to my color

[image]

here i want to change the sea blue kind of color to #37474F